# show similar item for ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am very new to AngularJS and am trying to design a news portal site, where the user click on the news heading, it will show the related news.

My HTML :

```
<table class='table'>
   <tr ng-repeat="newx in news.info  | filter:search">
   <td> 
      <h3> <a ng-click="show_sm(newx.newslinkText)">{{newx.newslinkText}}</a> </h3>
          <p> {{newx.newsText}}  </p>
   </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

My JS Controller ::

```
$scope.show_sm = function(str) {

   //$scope.news=
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Take a look at [ngShow](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow).

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-show to conditionally show the news content:

HTML :

```
<table class='table'>
   <tr ng-repeat="newx in news.info  | filter:search">
   <td> 
      <h3> <a ng-click="show_sm(newx)">{{newx.newslinkText}}</a> </h3>
          <p ng-show="selected == newx"> {{newx.newsText}}  </p>
   </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

JS:

Only show the news content if the news is currently selected:

```
$scope.show_sm = function(newx) {
   $scope.selected = newx;
}
```

Comment: I must disagree because once clicked you cannot hide it which is not ok. Also ng-show still renders the html but doesn't hide it.

Comment: which one you couldn't understand?
1. First $scope.selected has no value right? After executing show_sm you will populate $scope.selected with a value. After clicked again nothing will happen it will be still presented and rendered.
2. ng-show renders the <p> element but just hides it until selected==newx so this is not ok.

Comment: Nope, still don't understand what you're saying... feel free to provide an answer

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest using this one.

```
<table class='table'>
   <tr ng-repeat="newx in news.info  | filter:search">
     <td> 
      <h3> <a ng-click="show_sm(newx.newslinkText)">{{newx.newslinkText}}</a> </h3>
          <p ng-if="newx.selected> {{newx.newsText}}  </p>
     </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

And in the function you should have:

```
 $scope.show_sm = function(newx) {
      // At first click it will  be ! of false which is true and it will display the content
      $scope.newx.selected = !$scope.newx.selected;
   }
```